# How i create array from arraylist key & value in kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, arraylist, filter

My response is given below of array list, now i want to make new array list by ** job_date** key

```
"request": [
  {
    "id": 3,
    "company_id": 40,
    "job_id": 23,
    "job_date": "2021-07-22",
    "first_name": "Larry",
    "last_name": "P"
  },
  {
    "id": 8,
    "company_id": 44,
    "job_id": 27,
    "job_date": "2021-07-22",
    "first_name": "Larry",
    "last_name": "P"
  },
  {
    "id": 16,
    "company_id": 4,
    "job_id": 2,
    "job_date": "2021-07-01",
    "first_name": "Larry",
    "last_name": "P"
  }
]
```

I want output like below, Same date data in array

```
{
"2021-07-2": [
  {
    "id": 3,
    "company_id": 40,
    "job_id": 23,
    "first_name": "Larry",
    "last_name": "P"
  },
  {
    "id": 8,
    "company_id": 44,
    "job_id": 27,
    "first_name": "Larry",
    "last_name": "P"
  }
],
{
"2021-07-1": [
  {
    "id": 16,
    "company_id": 4,
    "job_id": 2,
    "first_name": "Larry",
    "last_name": "P"
  }
]
```

if anyone has an idea about that type of filter of ArrayList then comment on your answer.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I simplified data model but groupBy will work.

```
data class DatedRequest(val id: Int, val jobDate: String)
data class Request(val id: Int)

fun main() {
    val list = listOf(
        DatedRequest(1, "2021"),
        DatedRequest(2, "2021"),
        DatedRequest(3, "2020")
    )

    list.groupBy({ it.jobDate }, { Request(it.id) })
        .also(::print)
}
```

And result from print

```
{2021=[Request(id=1), Request(id=2)], 2020=[Request(id=3)]}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code.
First, convert JSON response to jsonString (let's call it response).

```
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    ObjectNode objectNode = (ObjectNode) mapper.readTree(response);
    ObjectNode objectNode2 = mapper.createObjectNode();
        for (int i = 0; i < objectNode.get("request").size(); i++) {
            String date = objectNode.get("request").get(i).get("job_date").asText().split(" ")[0];
            ObjectNode node = (ObjectNode) ((ObjectNode) objectNode.get("request").get(i));
            node.remove("job_date");
            if (objectNode2.has(date)) {
                ((ArrayNode) objectNode2.get(date)).add(node);
            } else {
                objectNode2.put(date, mapper.createArrayNode().add(node));
            }
        }
        System.out.println(objectNode2.toString());
```

Make sure you have validated your json